# Some Objects Show Up as System.__ComObject when Debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, com, solidworks

I'm interfacing with SolidWorks using C#.

I'm on Visual Studio 2017, latest release (15.7.3). The project references the SolidWorks `.tlb` files like the documentation says to do. On those references, I set "Embed Interop Types" to `false`, which allows me to see the type of the objects I'm dealing with when debugging, and look at any public properties etc.

For example, if I'm expecting a `FeatureManager`, it'll show up as `FeatureManagerClass`.

However, half of them still say `System.__ComObject`, like `SldWorks` or `ModelDoc2`, even though I can see `SldWorksClass` and `ModelDoc2Class` in the Object Browser.

When I run code analysis on the project, it rebuilds, and ~30 warnings will show up saying:

```
Processing COM reference 'SldWorks' from path "..." At least one of the arguments for "..." cannot be marshaled by the runtime marshaler.
```

or

```
Interface "..." is marked as [dual], but does not derive from IDispatch. It will be converted as an IUnknown-derived interface.
```

I don't know if these are separate issues. Just wondering if I can get all the types to show up properly.

Comment: Not exactly what you asking for but in the watch window you can manually cast your variables to see all the properties. I always assumes this to be a given handicap, not something you can fix. If you'll find a way please do share it.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem using VS 2015. In my case I was able to see the com objects types in the debugger by enabling the option "Use managed compatibility mode"

In visual studio if you open tools >> Options and then debugging >> General make sure the option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" is checked on.

This should show com objects as their proper types in the debugger.

Comment: The option to "use managed compatibility mode" was removed (deprecated) in Visual Studio 2022. Is there another way to do this?